# "Nonce too low" using contract.methods.myFunction().send()

Tags: web3js, infura

Using web3 to build a contract from the ABI:

```
contract = new web3.eth.Contract(JSON.parse(abi), '0x17c91A5a6f5e3E4BEaFC478D18C4A44D88833277', { from: '0x0Ad2b5CCe78D677fD000698a7E4Cde866DE189C6', gas: 100000})
```

`contract.methods.myFunction('constructorVariable1', 'constructorVariable2').send()`

First send completes successfully. Second+ send returns the error: `nonce too low`

- Truffle v5.1.13 (core: 5.1.13)
- Web3.js v1.2.1
- Ropsten testnet
- Infura as HDWalletProvider node

I can't find any documentation on manually increasing the nonce using the `send()` method. I would have also thought nonces would be increased automatically?

I should add that there were no pending transactions during these sends.

**Update**:

Disconnecting and reconnecting from `truffle console` resolved the issue.

Answer (score 2):

I ran to the same `nonce too low` message.  My issue was due to adding a wallet with a private key without the `0x` prefix - simply adding the `0x` prefix worked.  Here is my working code:

```
let account = web3.eth.accounts.wallet.add("0x8f88c79e3.......");

TestContract.methods.testFunction().send({
    from: account.address,
    gas: '1000000',
    value: 0,
});
```